# Facepy Error 803:Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: group_id

Tags: python, facepy

I'm trying to use configparser and pull the group ID from the config.

Basically the configparser is to pull the group ID from a separate config file and insert it into all of the group_id instances. What I think is happening is it is unable to read the group_id from the 'group_id/feed'.

```
group_id=config.get('settings','GROUPID')
```

and the facepy line itself is;

```
graph.post('group_id/feed', message=(random.choice(list(open('text.txt')))))
```

Here is the error I am getting

```
    File "C:\Users\0000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pac
kages\facepy\graph_api.py", line 96, in post
    retry=retry
  File "C:\Users\0000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pac
kages\facepy\graph_api.py", line 334, in _query
    return load_with_retry(method, url, data)[0]
  File "C:\Users\0000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pac
kages\facepy\graph_api.py", line 288, in load_with_retry
    return load(method, url, data)
  File "C:\Users\0000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pac
kages\facepy\graph_api.py", line 273, in load
    result = self._parse(response.content)
  File "C:\Users\0000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pac
kages\facepy\graph_api.py", line 404, in _parse
    raise exception(**self._get_error_params(data))
facepy.exceptions.OAuthError: [803] (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do
not exist: group_id
```

I have one already created to pull random text from a file and post to a user's page, now I'm trying to do it for groups, but am running into this issue.

I've tried to manually add in the ID and scrap the config and still get the same error.

Comment: This is too vague. please see [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Made it beefier, sorry about that. I didn't include what was needed and corrected it.